# C++ Why is reference to a contant a thing?

Tags: c++, reference, arguments, constants

Consider passing an argument via a constant vs via a reference to a constant

```
T function(T const  x) {}
T function(T const& x) {}
```

Constant already signify that the value will not be changed. Then why would a programmer need to specify whether to pass the argument by value or reference?

Should this optimization not be a decision made by the compiler?

For example, if the argument is of primitive type, such as `char` or `int`, then it is more cost effective to spawn a copy for the function to use.

If the argument of complex type, such as `std::string` or `std::vector` or even a user defined one, it it more cost effective for the function to handle it through reference.

However, these decision are not dilemma where the programmer have to make a compromise that would impact performance in any way.

In my point of view, the use of reference to constant is redundant. Stating that an argument is of a constant nature should be enough, and the compiler should be the one that handle whether to pass it by value or by reference.

Comment: What if T isn't copyable?

Comment: Part of your question seemed like critique of language design. No one can change it much as C++ is decades old and unimaginable amount of important software is written in it.